# What is the requirement to make database engine?

Tags: database, sqlite, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Windows Event Log viewer]

I would like to make a light database engine that will record some of of events of IoT, more or less will be like that Windows Event Log viewer. I don't have idea how a database engine works. I expect it can record the events, like when it *start/stop*, something like every event will be have its own *Event ID* and *open/close* with respective start and close respectively in another column, its *severity level* (critical, major, minor, info, etc) in one column, and the description of the events in another column. So, it will be around 7 column. I expect that it can be sorted by the event code, the status (open/close), and its severity level.

My question is, is it ***possible*** to make such light database engine that will be fit for small resources? ***Possible*** in here should be translated to, "Is any such light database engine that is used in many application that I can compare?" What is the requirement to make it? I will write it in C/C++.

***Note***: When filling the *tags*, I didn't see *engine* or *database-engine*, maybe someone need to add them.